# generate a root certificate for MitmProxy

Tags: openssl

Hi i which to generate a root certificate for MitmProxy app
it exists 4 cer's in home location

mitmproxy-ca.pem    The private key and certificate in PEM format.
mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem   The certificate in PEM format. Use this to distribute to most non-Windows platforms.
mitmproxy-ca-cert.p12   The certificate in PKCS12 format. For use on Windows.
mitmproxy-ca-cert.cer   Same file as .pem, but with an extension expected by some Android devices.

At the moment it generates the certificate issuer as MitmProxy i've search'd the source code that is built on python
Please help i wish to generate my own cert's or change the source code so it generates an other issuer

Sorry for the bad english
//Sm(9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using a custom certificate

You can use your own certificate by passing the --cert option to mitmproxy.

The certificate file is expected to be in the PEM format. You can generate a certificate in this format using these instructions:

```
openssl genrsa -out cert.key 8192
openssl req -new -x509 -key cert.key -out cert.crt
  (Specify the mitm domain as Common Name, e.g. *.google.com)
cat cert.key cert.crt > cert.pem
mitmproxy --cert=cert.pem
```

For more details [visit the MITM documentation](http://mitmproxy.org/doc/ssl.html), *where this answer was copied from*.

Also note at the time of this writing that a 8192-bit cert is being recommended

Answer (score 8):

You can use your own certificate with the mitmproxy's --cert option.

```
> openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
> openssl req -new -x509 -key ca.key -out ca.crt

   ... No need to fill out optional fields ...
   Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []:*.google.com  (domain you want to MITM here)
   ...

> cat ca.key ca.crt > ca.pem 
> mitmproxy --cert=ca.pem
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question the op is asking.  He wants to generate a CA certificate that mitmproxy will use to sign the bogus certificates mitmproxy creates for each SSL site.  The --cert option merely allows you to provide certs to use for specific domains (instead of having mitmproxy generate a certificate on the fly).  What he wants is the --confdir option and needs to generate his own CA signing certificate.

Answer (score 4):

`mitmproxy` stores the certs in `~/.mitmproxy`. I have these files:

```
mitmproxy-ca-cert.cer
mitmproxy-ca-cert.p12
mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem
mitmproxy-ca.pem
mitmproxy-dhparam.pem
```

You should try replacing these.

Comment: Also, look at [CertStore.create_store()](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/5f74adc2df6d2a9452a9e3a6923fe05ba579e9e6/mitmproxy/certs.py#L198) from mitmproxy source code for the generation steps (it uses OpenSSL bindings). Re-using that module as standalone is possible with minor changes.

Answer (score 3):

Took me forever to figure out and I'm still amazed that I couldn't find any documentation of this. The key was to look at [how mitmproxy creates this file.](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/2dd845ed95db54be2a9548e54f3fcdc6c82d472a/mitmproxy/certs.py#L168)

I created my own simplified version of their technique. This is how you generate your own custom `mitmproxy-ca.pem` file with python:

```py
import datetime

from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.x509 import ExtendedKeyUsageOID, NameOID

KEY_SIZE = 2048
CA_EXPIRY = datetime.timedelta(days=10 * 365)

ORGANIZATION = "anything"
CN = "anything"

def create_ca():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        public_exponent=65537,
        key_size=KEY_SIZE,
    )
    name = x509.Name([
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, CN),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, ORGANIZATION)
    ])
    builder = x509.CertificateBuilder()
    builder = builder.serial_number(x509.random_serial_number())
    builder = builder.subject_name(name)
    builder = builder.not_valid_before(now - datetime.timedelta(days=2))
    builder = builder.not_valid_after(now + CA_EXPIRY)
    builder = builder.issuer_name(name)
    builder = builder.public_key(private_key.public_key())
    builder = builder.add_extension(x509.BasicConstraints(
        ca=True, path_length=None), critical=True)
    builder = builder.add_extension(x509.ExtendedKeyUsage(
        [ExtendedKeyUsageOID.SERVER_AUTH]), critical=False)
    builder = builder.add_extension(
        x509.KeyUsage(
            digital_signature=False,
            content_commitment=False,
            key_encipherment=False,
            data_encipherment=False,
            key_agreement=False,
            key_cert_sign=True,
            crl_sign=True,
            encipher_only=False,
            decipher_only=False,
        ), critical=True)
    builder = builder.add_extension(x509.SubjectKeyIdentifier.from_public_key(
        private_key.public_key()), critical=False)
    cert = builder.sign(private_key=private_key,
                        algorithm=hashes.SHA256())
    return private_key, cert
```

Now that you've generated a key and a properly configured certificate, you can combine them and write it to a `.pem` file:

```py
key, ca = create_ca() # to run the function above
key = key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption(),
)
ca = ca.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM)

pem_content = key+ca

with open("mitmproxy-ca.pem", "wb") as w:
    w.write(pem_content)
```

You should put this `mitmproxy-ca.pem` file in a directory and then reference that directory with the mitmproxy `--set confdir=/certdir` option.

You would also probably want to distribute a certificate to the clients so that they can install it. You should distribute only the certificate. Like this:

```py
key, ca = create_ca() # from earlier, do not repeat

with open("cert_to_install.pem", "wb") as w:
    w.write(ca)
```

To be clear, this is the file you install for example on your iPhone/Android phone or on your computer.

**BONUS:**
To verify that your `mitmproxy-ca.pem` file is usable, [the mitmproxy docs](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/#using-a-custom-certificate-authority) propose you verify it with this command:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in mitmproxy-ca.pem
```

The output should contain:

```
X509v3 extensions:
    X509v3 Key Usage: critical
        Certificate Sign
    X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
        CA:TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Customizing certificate info can be achieved by editing mitmproxy python file directly, but you need to find those script files firstly.In my case, those mitmproxy module files is under **/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mitmproxy/**.

Take mitmproxy version v5.3.0 for example:

To change **expiry**, **organization** and **CN**, you can customize the default parameters of [create_store](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/v5.3.0/mitmproxy/certs.py#L233) in certs.py:

```py
@staticmethod
def create_store(path, basename, key_size, organization="some org", cn="some cn", expiry=157680000 ):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
```

Remember to **delete certificate files firstly** every time you want to change the certificate info.

To find the mitmproxy module path if you're interested: 
`` vi `which mitmproxy` ``

```py
import mitmproxy
print(mitmproxy.__file__)
```

`mitmproxy`